# How to Show The Full Screen of Html5 Video in IE or FF

Tags: css, asp.net, html5-video

I've researched this topic for quite sometime now and haven't been able to find any conclusive answers.

I've a template that creates an html5 video but that template is created on two separate events and has a different set of CSS with either call.

In one call, the video element is rendered with full screen and all is well.
In the other, the full screen button is missing and in Chrome I managed to solve it using video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button  display option in CSS.

Now I started checking other options and I see that the button is missing, and I don't see any other css options I can depend upon.

My question is, other than using custom controls, what else can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your template changes something, or doesn't add for example "control" attribute.

Here is a simple example of HTML5 Video, and full-screen option works in all modern browsers: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Click "Try it Yourself >>" to see the code.

Comment: you accidently stumbled upon my problem, the link you sent has the controls div under the player, but it has download option and not full screen! ... at least to me (could it be my client is somehow screwed?)

Comment: I'll be more specific, the link has the video with the full screen option. but when you use the try it yourself option, the video simulated does not have the full screen option.

Comment: apparently it's because the video is in an iframe. Is it the case for you?
But don't know why...

Comment: It seems to be the case.. at least from the attempts I've made to solve it, I've come across that possibility and it seems to be the most plausible options, thanks.

Comment: Tested, it  turns out your theory is correct, thanks. :)